# Assigning a character array in Fortran

Tags: string, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, character-arrays

I'm having to write a subroutine that can be called both by C and by Fortran. This subroutine takes a file name as one of its arguments. I know that to interoperate nicely with C, the ISO C binding recommends using character arrays for interoperation.

The question I have is: is there such a thing as a character array literal that's easy to write? I have a subroutine like this:

```
subroutine my_sub(char_array)
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_char
  char(kind=c_char, len=1), dimension(:), intent(in) :: char_array
  ...
end subroutine my_sub
```

Is it possible to invoke this with something like:

```
call my_sub('Hello World!')
```

Or do I have to do something horrible like:

```
call my_sub((/ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!' /))
```

My main issue seems to be that it doesn't like the assumed-shape array and that giving it a set (large) size also outputs all the garbage memory that happens to get picked up afterwards.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules of sequence association allow similar situation. You can use

```
call my_sub('Hello World!')
```

but only if you make your array assumed size `dimension(*)` or explicit shape.

Generally, in Fortran 2008 you cannot use assumed shape arrays for C-interoperable procedures. This will change i the future, but will be more complicated.

One other important remark. Just using `iso_c_binding` module  doesn't make the procedure C-interoperable. **You have to use `bind(C)`**, possibly with binding name. That's the important thing. You can create interoperable procedures even without the module (only limited ones). The feature of passing the string instead of 1-character array also depends on this.

This is why i don't like saying "use iso_c_binding to create interoperable procedures".

The interface to the procedure will have to explicit in Fortran.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bind(C) and the name (I use various different compilers, so I want to ensure that I'm getting consistent naming, as far as possible).

Comment: `bind(C)` is the key! Even `iso_c_binding` is less important, and here almost not needed, it just contains couple of constants and procedures.

Comment: Oh, I meant in my code snippet. I have bind(C) in all of my subroutines. :)

Comment: Ok, unfortunately, `gfortran` accepts the assumed shape array even though it is clearly a problem here. With `ifort` I get `error #8520: An array dummy argument of a BIND(C) procedure must be an explicit shape or assumed size array.` It may be relaxed now, but a warning would be in order anyway I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use transfer function. Here is an example code.

```
program string0
  implicit none
  character, allocatable :: string(:)
  character(len = :), allocatable :: text

  text = 'this is a pen'
  string = transfer(text, ' ', size = len_trim(text))
  string = achar(iachar(string) - 32)
  text = transfer(string, text)
  print *, text

  stop
end program string0
```

Comment: Good to see a short explanation on the example, e.g. what `transfer` function does and what arguments it gets.